# Seam conversation context basics

Tags: selenium-webdriver, seam2, jboss-arquillian

I'm new to this Seam stuff and am also trying to move forward with Arquillian.

In the setup of our Selenium (WebDriver) tests, I am attempting to utilize builder classes that utilize entity managers so the scope of the UI test is specific only to its purpose.

However, I ultimately receive an error because a Conversation Context does not exist.  I know the solution to this is involving, but would like to quickly get up to speed just enough to get this going.  I have a handful of references about the subject that I will use to fill in the gaps later.

I realize this is vague.  What other information would I need to provide in order to get some useful feedback on this?

***Edit:***

I'm working with this as a solution: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ARQ/Seam+2, but am getting the following as the root cause in my stack:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WEB-INF/web.xml not found in classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@3182f0db
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.asset.ClassLoaderAsset.<init>(ClassLoaderAsset.java:70)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.asset.ClassLoaderAsset.<init>(ClassLoaderAsset.java:45)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.container.WebContainerBase.setWebXML(WebContainerBase.java:94)
    ... 55 more
```

The only web.xml location is in another project outside of the qa, but is referenced as a dependency in the pom.

Just to reiterate, I'm attempting to work around a non-existent Seam conversation context when attempting to utilize builder components in my setup for a Selenium (WebDriver) UI test.  I'd like to learn how to put all of this stuff together as I am at the momemnt unfamiliar with this tech stack.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  I imagine posting the error itself, along with the relevant snippet of code that produced it, would help you get more feedback.

Comment: Thanks ASGM.  This is more of a high level question, but I edited my original post to at least give some additional context and updated efforts.

Comment: Have you tried `setWebXML("actual-path/web.xml")` ? Im not sure I get it, what is your question, really?

Comment: @acdcjunior Yes, I've tried the full path as well.  The original post is a question of _"how do I do this?"_, but can be summed up with _"how can I use other seam components within my selenium tests for setup via an Arquillian runner?"_

Comment: If this is still actual, post how do you create the deployment archive. Arquillian creates a war archive to run the tests.